# A short story from 1968-1971 about alien archeologists re-animating human remains for questioning

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a story that was written like a report concerning two scientists studying the dead civilization of Earth.  They did this by re-animating dust and bones and asking the formerly dead person what happened. They had little success until the last being they re-animated said "We made a mistake. I can fix this. Everything will be fine." Apparently he did. We also learned that the scientists were aliens.

Answer (score 10):

It sounds a bit like [The Monster/Resurrection](http://variety-sf.blogspot.co.uk/2008/03/e-van-vogt-monster-aka-resurrection.html) by A. E. Van Vogt, though I think this was written well before 1968.

Comment: To help out the original poster, Resurrection had the following humans brought back to life in the following order: a Pharaoh expecting an Egyptian afterlife with slaves and servants, a drunk automobile driver, a man who could use several of the advanced machines in the museum where they were being resurrected, and a telepathic, teleporting advanced human who instantly knew why the aliens were resurrecting humans and what to do with the aliens.  That probably doesn't answer your question, unless the "scientists" were aliens.

Answer (score 4):

There was a book about alien archeologists conducting a "dig" on earth.  I believe the title was [*43,000 Years Later*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?20641), by [Horace Coon](http://sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/coon_horace_c).

I lost the book before I was able to finish it, so it may fit your description.  It had some interesting observations concerning life as we know it.  I have been unable to find the book since my loss.  I hope you have better luck.

Comment: Amazon has *43,000 Years Later* for $3 plus shipping. It doesn't look like the same book though.

Comment: [Amazon Link](http://www.amazon.com/Years-Later-First-Paperback-Edition/dp/B000BPFBJ4)