# Trying to identify a short sci-fi story about a human that is "resurrected" by malignant aliens

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to locate a short sci-fi story I read years ago about a human that is "resurrected" by an arrogant and malignant alien species that discovers him in a "museum" on an earth where the inhabitants, though very advanced, had been wasted by a close encounter (I believe) with a neutron star.
He is the third or fourth human they "reconstruct" and it turns out that he is an advanced mentalist, disappearing at the moment of his "resurrection".
He outwits the aliens and eventually tricks them into plunging their ship into the sun in order (they think) to prevent him from finding out where they come from.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 29):

This is [The Monster/Resurrection](http://variety-sf.blogspot.co.uk/2008/03/e-van-vogt-monster-aka-resurrection.html) by A. E. Van Vogt.

Actually I've ID'd this story before in [A short story from 1968-1971 about alien archeologists re-animating human remains for questioning](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19976/a-short-story-from-1968-1971-about-alien-archeologists-re-animating-human-remain/19989).

Comment: Spot on bullseye! Thank you!

Comment: I remember reading this in some story collection when I was a kid. Really weird seeing it again here >_>

Comment: "The Monster" is a classic.  Randall Garrett wrote a comedy short story that name-checked this one... aliens who believed a human had amazing powers said "we've got a monster here", and from what I know about Randall Garrett this was almost certainly an intended affectionate hat-tip to "The Monster".  It's a funny story, called "The Best Policy" and it's available in this collection: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Best_of_Randall_Garrett

Comment: Should you ever return, @Clark, don't forget to mark the answer as Accepted.

Comment: http://www.prosperosisle.org/spip.php?article220 A link to the story