# Alien invaders land on a devastated earth and resurrect a human

Tags: story-identification, aliens

A story in which alien invaders land on a devastated earth and resurrect a human.

The humans had reached a very advanced stage but had been destroyed by a natural disaster which they didn't have the time to prevent.

The aliens now try to destroy this human but he tricks them into blowing themselves up.

Comment: Is this movie, book, short story. When did you see/read it?

Comment: Sounds like every episode of "Allo, Allo"

Comment: Try to give as much information as possible. As it stands this question is likely to be closed.

Comment: This sounds like http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33610/trying-to-identify-a-short-sci-fi-story-about-a-human-that-is-resurrected-by-m

Comment: @andrewsi Yes, but story-ID questions can't be closed as duplicate until the OP has confirmed the answer, according to site policy.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - indeed; but since no one else had made the link, I thought it might be an idea to do so.

Comment: @Skooba This is at least the 8th question we've had about Van Vogt's "Resurrection" aka "The Monster", which is just one of the most famous sci-fi stories of all time, and one line is enough to identify if. But I don't doubt that you're right, the ignorant will close the question as "too broad" or "unclear".

Comment: @user14111 Yes, I added the "likely to be closed" as it was from Review. Your comment and seeing the question again has made me retract mine.

Answer (score 10):

I believe this is "The Monster" by A E Van Vogt. In this short story an alien ship lands on a lifeless earth and enter a museum. Using a resurrection machine and small fragments of skull bone, they restore several humans to life - beginning with an egyptian mummy and ending with a highly advanced human who outsmarts the aliens.

Comment: Right. And you can read it for free at [archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v41n06_1948-08_cape1736#page/n55/mode/2up).