# An advanced alien species landing on Earth after it has been destroyed

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A short story about an advanced and aggressive alien species landing on Earth that has been destroyed many years ago, possibly by an asteroid.

The visitors resurrect the humans starting from a very primitive type (which they immediately destroy) and ultimately bring back a very advanced human which in the end tricks them into destroying themselves before they can go back and bring reinforcements.

Comment: Please specify language, year when you read it. That may help people to answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to identify a short sci-fi story about a human that is "resurrected" by malignant aliens](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33610/trying-to-identify-a-short-sci-fi-story-about-a-human-that-is-resurrected-by-m)

Comment: @waldrumpus Which would make it a possible dupe of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19976/a-short-story-from-1968-1971-about-alien-archeologists-re-animating-human-remain/19989 too. And, while we're at it, also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/139084/alien-invaders-land-on-a-devastated-earth-and-resurrect-a-human

Comment: @waldrumpus You may be right, but according to [policy](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7067/31394) we can't close a story-ID question as duplicate **unless the OP has confirmed the answer**. Menon, is van Vogt's *The Monster/Resurrection* the story you're thinking of?

Comment: Van Vogt's *The Monster*: https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v41n06_1948-08_cape1736#page/n55/mode/2up

Answer (score 3):

A.E. Van Vogt's [The Monster](http://www.prosperosisle.org/spip.php?article220) is exactly what you've described.

Comment: An otherwise fine story somewhat ruined by its demand for *two* gazeeka boxes in a single plot - the resurrection machine and the magical method for finding planets. The logic that leads to them resurrecting the final specimen is also somewhat laughably bad.