# Sci-Fi story where aliens resurrect humans, who have gone extinct

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Can you help me identify a story by this poorly recollected plot line? I probably read the story when I was 12 so 50+ years ago.

Aliens arrive on a dead planet earth and begin to resurrect various long dead humans. A cave man and a man who died drunk in a car wreck and finally a human who disappears as soon as he is resurrected. Turns out earth had been surprised by a radiation belt that wiped out everyone because of its huge size. The aliens tried to eliminate the last human they had brought back but couldn't. All was trending well for the humans when the story ended.

Poor description from a poor memory but I would appreciate it if anyone knows where I could read the story again

Comment: The interwebs are truly amazing. I wondered what the name of the story was for 35 years and you answered the question two minutes after I uploaded it. Thank you Jeff.

Comment: Apparently a popular one, as it was also identified (though not confirmed) as an answer to this question too: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19976/a-short-story-from-1968-1971-about-alien-archeologists-re-animating-human-remain/19989

Answer (score 12):

["Resurrection"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?63317) aka "The Monster" by [A. E. van Vogt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._E._van_Vogt), first published in [*Astounding Science Fiction*, August 1948](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57412+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v41n06_1948-08_cape1736#page/n55/mode/2up).

Comment: I was also looking for this, thanks.