# Story Identification : Aliens revive museum humans

Tags: story-identification

An alien race finds Earth.  Its landing party locates a museum or some such facility and one-by-one, the aliens revivify deceased humans in the museum.

Most who awaken (such as a Pharaoh) are quickly deemed to be uninteresting and inferior and destroyed. But the last such person sits up, looks around, and promptly disappears.

Does anyone recognize this story line?  I probably read this 50 years ago.

Comment: Previously identified as a dupe of [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37336/sci-fi-story-where-aliens-resurrect-humans-who-have-gone-extinct/37337#37337) and [this one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33610/trying-to-identify-a-short-sci-fi-story-about-a-human-that-is-resurrected-by-m/33620#33620) and maybe [this one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19976/a-short-story-from-1968-1971-about-alien-archeologists-re-animating-human-remain/19989#19989).

Answer (score 6):

Almost certainly this is the classic story ["The Monster/Resurrection"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/69300/dead-earth-aliens-revive-human) by A. E. Van Vogt.

@User14111 has previously identified the story (along with a review and extensive quotes) [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/69300/dead-earth-aliens-revive-human)

Comment: This must be the most Frequently Asked Question in the story-id tag.

Comment: @user14111 - Right up there with "Light Brigade"

Comment: Up there with **what???** Oh, I see. A recent TV show. No wonder I never heard of it.

Comment: I do appreciate that you like your sci-fi Golden Aged or thereabouts...http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/5108/20774

Comment: It's a powerful story with advanced technologies, right up there with the reconstitution/resurrection machine in The Fifth Element that operated in a similar fashion.