# Short story about the last man left alive who can reanimate the dead

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

1. The story has to do with the last man left alive at the end of civilization. His name was Galen Garr or Galen Gann or something to that effect.
2. He has the power to raise the dead, but he finds "the city of the undead to be worse and more full of madness than the city of the living" (my recollection)
3. But this guy is a big proclaimer. "I, Galen Garr, will try again and raise the race of men!" (etc.)
4. He uses his power, and does this.  Comes face-to-face with a single individual (maybe on a throne?). That person is... the last person left alive after another era of humanoids or human beings.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, did you read it in an anthology, a magazine, or online?

Comment: Not sure of year of publication.  Read this at least a decade ago.  Not sure of the source, either.  Definitely a short story, though.

Comment: At first glance - Seems similar to (not claiming it is) https://variety-sf.blogspot.com/2008/03/e-van-vogt-monster-aka-resurrection.html?m=1  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19976/a-short-story-from-1968-1971-about-alien-archeologists-re-animating-human-remain/19989

Comment: Though suspiciously the Galen name in the question is similar to Ganae the aliens that resurrect people.  Full story at https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v41n06_1948-08_cape1736/page/n55/mode/2up?view=theater

Answer (score 33):

If you have the name slightly off, and it's really "Galos Gann" then this is probably "[In the World's Dusk](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?63337)" (1936) by Edmond Hamilton.

> **For Galos Gann was the last man of all men**. Sitting alone in his darksome hall high in somber Zor, he knew that nowhere around the desert globe did there move another human shape nor echo another human voice. He was that one about whom during anticipatory ages a fearful, foreboding fascination had clung—the final survivor.

He names himself when making grandiose statements:

> He said, "You think that you look down on the last of men, that all the glories of my race are a story that is told and ended, but you are wrong, **I am Galos Gann, the greatest man of all the men that have lived on earth. And it is my unconquerable will that my race shall not die** but shall live on to greater glories."

In order to restore the race of man he reanimates the dead:

> Then **Galos Gann began to work upon the bodies of the dead**, summoning up from his mighty resolution superhuman scientific powers which even he had hitherto never possessed.
>
> By supreme chemical achievement he synthesized new blood with which he filled the wasted veins of the bodies. And by powerful electric stimulants and glandular injections he set their hearts to beating convulsively, and then regularly. And as their hearts pumped the new blood through their bodies to their perfectly preserved brains, **the dead regained slow consciousness and staggered upright and looked dazedly at one another and at the watching Galos Gann**.

Galos Gann rejects the no-longer-dead because they can't bear children who truly live:

> Galos Gann told them darkly, "Return then to the nothingness you crave, since you cannot serve my purpose. But know that not now and not ever shall I relinquish my purpose to perpetuate the race."

Next Galos Gann tries to draw people from the past to restart the human race, but they are all driven insane by being dragged through time:

> Finally Galos Gann ceased to draw men and women out of the past, for he saw that never could he hope to bring them through sane. For a time he strove to replace the minds of these crazed people which had been destroyed. But he saw that that too was beyond the power of any material science.
>
> Then in **that shrieking city of madness** which was the last city on earth, Galos Gann grew afraid that he too was going mad. He felt a desire to scream with the others through the dark streets.

Galos Gann finally decides to return Earth to a primordial condition and restart evolution, to breed a new race of man; and he will sleep until it arises:

> Galos Gann in his deep-buried chamber watched through his instruments and saw the changes taking place upon the surface of the earth. He saw the upthrust masses of molten magma give off their imprisoned gases, and observed those gases combining to form a new hydrosphere of water-vapor clouds around the planet.
>
> The earth was passing through the same changes it had passed through long ago. As its molten surface began to cool, rain began to fall from the clouds and gathered upon the tom surface of the world in new seas.

But he sleeps too long and finds only a sole survivor like himself:

> He came to one of its open gates and passed into the city. And like a man in a dream he walked through the streets, turning his head this way and that. For **this city was as empty of life as ancient Zor had been. Not in any of its courts or ways did there move one human shape, nor echo one human voice**. And now a fatal foreboding and knowledge came upon Galos Gann, and led him into the highest tower and up to a dim and dusky hall at the tower's top.
>
> There at the end of the hall sat huddled in his robes a withered, shrunken man who seemed very near to death.
>
> Galos Gann spoke to him in a strange voice and said, "Who are you, and where are the others of the races of men?"
>
> The other raised his swaying head, and peering blindly at Galos Gann he answered, "There are no others, for **I am the last survivor of all the race of man**."

The story was first published in *Weird Tales*, March 1936, and can be read at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/WeirdTales193603ATLPM/page/n89/mode/2up).